# How to get correct driver for old sound card....I don't know brand and model no of sound card

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sound-card

How to get correct driver for old sound card....I don't know brand and model no of sound card...

My os is windows XP 32 bit.

Sound card is external cad and it's attached to motherboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and run **[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/download/siw.exe)**.

under **Hardware** click on **PCI** and identify the 'audio device'.

### Update

You can download the ALS4000 Audio Driver for Windows XP [here](http://www.softwarepatch.com/utilities/als4000.html).

Comment: thx for this info. Vendor is Avance Logic Inc and Device is ALS4000 Audio Chipset

Comment: @Jitendra vyas - updated my post according to your info.

Answer (score 0):

If it shows up in Device Manager, you can check the Device ID(1) on http://www.pcidatabase.com

This will tell you the manufacturer/model/number etc, and links to contact for the driver (or to help you google)
Haven't tested with external sound-cards though.. question seems resolved, posted anyway, for posterity.

(1) Device Manager -> Item (right-click) "Properties" -> "Details" tab -> select "Hardware IDs"